# How do I compile a Code Composer project which was created using a different version of Code Generation tools?

Tags: code-generation, texas-instruments, code-composer

I have a Code Composer project I received from a friend. When I try to build it I get the following error message:

> This project was created using a
>   version of Code Generation tools that
>   is not currently installed: 6.1.12
>   [C6000]. Please install the Code
>   Generation tools of this version, or
>   migrate the project to one of the
>   supported versions.

How do I migrate the project to my version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to hack it - the project file is plaintext.

Open the file, compare it to a project file created with your version.  Change any differences obviously related to versioning to look like your native file.

As an alternate, just create a new project with your IDE, then manually add all the source files listed in the friend's project file..

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple links to the TI wiki that describe migration of projects between CCS versions:
http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Importing_Projects_into_CCS
http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/GSG:Importing_projects_from_previous_versions